# Objective C function that returns a struct not compiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code in my iPhone app

```
CGPoint p = [StaticClass doSomethingWithA:a doSomethingWithB:b];
```

but when I compile I get the following error:

error: conversion from 'objc_object*' to non-scalar type 'CGPoint' requested

Here is the prototype for my function:

```
+(CGPoint) doSomethingWithA:(UIImage*) from doSomethingWithB:(UIImage*) to
{
     // Do Some stuff 
     return CGPointMake(ret.x, ret.y);
}
```

I think this is kind of a noob question but I've been doing app development for a while (self taught) and have kept running in to this and I don't have a formal understanding of Objective C so I don't know what is going on

It seems strange that you would *HAVE* to return a pointer type from any method ... and I feel like I've definitely done stuff like this with flotas or ints before

Thanks

Comment: You've shown the method definition from your .m file; can you also show the method declaration from your .h file? Also, use the "101010" button to format code.

Comment: I just compiled a class method that returns a CGPoint (exactly as your example does) without any error. I suspect the error is elsewhere in your code, or the code you've posted here isn't an exact reflection of the code you actually have.

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't import the correct header file, which means the compiler doesn't know what the method returns and can't generate the correct calling code.

Also, that's not a function, it's a class method. A function would look like:

```
CGPoint doSomethingWithImages(UIImage *from, UIImage *to) {
    // Do Some stuff 
    return CGPointMake(ret.x, ret.y);
}

// Elsewhere …

CGPoint p = doSomethingWithImages(a, b);
```